# How combine two long press buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

I am a beginner in programming android. 
Is there any way to combine two long press buttons with an Android service and react to that?
I want to combine two long press buttons (home & volume down ) for activate wifi even if the phone is locked.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than connecting to the long press listener..

Connect to the button press listener.
Check when the button is pressed down, and when it is lifted up.

Measure the time between these 2 events. Was it long enough to be classed as a long press?

Were both buttons pressed down long enough at the same time?..

If you want to trigger while they are down still, just ensure the up event hasnt fired yet after 2 seconds for example.

Comment: Thanks
if you have tutorial for example

Comment: @Android08 From a service im not sure it is actually possible.